# Deleting A Specific FIle WIth Filename From All Sub-directories In PHP

Tags: php, file

Suppose there's a directory in which there are numerous sub-directories. Now how can I scan all the subdirectories to find a file with name, say, **abc.php** and delete this file wherever its is found.

I tried doing something like this -

```
$oAllSubDirectories = scandir(getcwd());
foreach ($oAllSubDirectories as $oSubDirectory)
{
  //Delete code here
}
```

But this code doesn't check directories inside the subdirectories. Any idea how can I do this ?

Comment: http://www.kerstner.at/en/2011/12/recursively-delete-files-using-php/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, you put the code inside a function and make it recursive: when it encounters a directory it calls itself in order to process its contents. Something like this:

```
function processDirectoryTree($path) {
    foreach (scandir($path) as $file) {
        $thisPath = $path.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$file;
        if (is_dir($thisPath) && trim($thisPath, '.') !== '') {
            // it's a directory, call ourself recursively
            processDirectoryTree($thisPath);
        }
        else {
            // it's a file, do whatever you want with it
        }
    }
}
```

In this particular case you don't need to do that because PHP offers the ready-made [`RecursiveDirectoryIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php) that does this automatically:

```
$it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator(getcdw()));
while($it->valid()) {
    if ($it->getFilename() == 'abc.php') {
        unlink($it->getPathname());
    }
    $it->next();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying @Jon, just one question.. What is **DS** in above code ($path.DS.$file) ?

Comment: @SachynKosare: Actually it was a mistake on my part. I meant [`DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`](http://php.net/manual/en/dir.constants.php). It's a built-in PHP constant.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Jon,  this is all I wanted.. RecursiveIteratorIterator works perfectly..